# ggplot facet wrap variable as an argument in a function

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to write a function where one of the arguments is the variable by which to facet wrap.

Minimum reproducible example:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)

wobble<- matrix(1:9, 3) %>% as_tibble()


wibble_fun <- function(df, var) {
   df %>%
     ggplot(aes(var)) +
     geom_bar() + 
     facet_wrap(~var)
}


wibble_fun(wobble, "V1")
```

The resulting error:

```
Error: At least one layer must contain all faceting variables: `var`.
* Plot is missing `var`
* Layer 1 is missing `
```

Seems like `var` in `facet_wrap(~var)` is interpreted as the string 'var' instead of being substituted by "V1", which is the second argument when I call the function.

Is there a way to make this work?

Comment: It looks like you can use a string directly in `facet_wrap`, just drop the `~`.

Answer (score 9):

Here's a solution using `{{...}}` around the variable within the function instead of using `sym` and unqoting:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)

wobble<- matrix(1:9, 3) %>% as_tibble()


wibble_fun <- function(df, var) {
   df %>%
     ggplot(aes({{var}})) +
     geom_bar() + 
     facet_wrap(vars({{var}}))
}


wibble_fun(wobble, V1)
```

Comment: I got stuck with using two variables.  Just in case someone needs it, you would do facet_wrap(vars{{var1}}, {{var2}}) - this blog post has some links to why. https://community.rstudio.com/t/referencing-variables-in-functions-using/43806

Answer (score 3):

I think an easy fix to your problem would be using `[[` to pass the column `var` into your function:

```
    wibble_fun <- function(df, var) {
     df %>%
     ggplot(aes(df[[var]])) +
     geom_bar() + 
     facet_wrap(~df[[var]])
}


wibble_fun(wobble, "V1")
```

Answer (score 2):

A different way to do this makes use of Non-Standard Evaluation which, while confusing, is the "official" way to do things like this in the `tidyverse`.

We use the `sym` function to convert `var` from a string into a `symbol`, then unquote it with `!!` in the `aes`.

For the `facet_wrap`: as [marius](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1222578/marius) pointed out in the comments, `facet_wrap` can accept a string or symbol instead of a formula (made with `~`). You can either pass in your symbol `x` or the string `var` itself: you'll get the same results.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)

wobble<- matrix(1:9, 3) %>% as_tibble()


wibble_fun <- function(df, var) {
    x = sym(var)
    df %>%
        ggplot(aes(!!x)) +
        geom_bar() + 
        facet_wrap(x)
}


wibble_fun(wobble, "V1")
```

[image: Plot]

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to rename `V1` in `df` as `var`:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)
wobble <- matrix(1:9, 3) %>% as_tibble()   

wibble_fun <- function(df, var) {
   df %>%
   rename(var=!!var) %>%
     ggplot(aes(var)) +
     geom_bar() + 
     facet_wrap(~var) +
     xlab(var)
}

wibble_fun(wobble, "V1")
```

[image]